# Tex Studio: PDF not updating after compiling?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, miktex

I am using Tex Studio for making a document in Latex. unfortunately, I'm facing a problem. when I compile my document main file after changing in the text, it does not apply on pdf view. what would be the solution to this problem?

Comment: You should provide more information about your configuration to narrow down the problem like which command line options are given to pdflatex.
Usually, a missing synctex file or option causes this problem.

Comment: Are you using `Build and View` (default shortcut is F5)? If you are, and pdf view is not updating, probably `txs:///view-pdf` is not being passed. Please show us your build configuration (`Configure TeXstudio -> Build` with "Show Advanced Options" checked on the bottom left corner of the dialog window).

Comment: What if you press F7? Does the pdf view refresh (do you see the changes you made in the previous compilation?)

Comment: Troy's answere worked for me

Comment: On a fresh install of TeXstudio 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 22.04, I'm facing the same problem : Both F5 (Build & View) and F6 (Compile) do not make the PDF viewer refresh (both embedded and external: Gnome's Evince). Only F7 (View) updates the embedded view. @Troy, which build configuration would you like to see? However, for the external PDF viewer, the reason is because my system is plagged by tracker eating all the available capacity of inotify watches (despite having 65536 watches available). Could it be that TeXstudio also uses inotify? Although in case of F5, a refresh should be forced, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

First I press ctrl + L + Backspace, then compiling again, you will see all the reference and citation display "?". Next, use delete the file .text in your folder, then complie again, the change will be applied